# Having a code on website that works with alert but doesn't link to another website when the if condition is met

Tags: javascript, html, validation, if-statement, alert

I am having trouble with my HTML/JAVASCRIPT document i have copied the code below.

I have created an input textbox and a button which runs function check(). The code executes well by using alerts but when i substitute the alert to a link that will direct the user to a webpage when the condition is met.

In my example the condition is 40.

I have an external stylesheet linked to the document and an external Javascript script attached as well.

Thanks...

**EDIT** - this might be easier i have made a simple file with all the code i want excecuted below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function check (){
    var codeEntered = document.getElementById("promocode").value;
      if (codeEntered==40)
  {
 //alert ("work")
 window.location.assign = "http://www.w3schools.com";
  }
  else if (codeEntered == "")
  {
  alert ("Please Enter a Promotional Code.")  
  }
  else
  {
  alert ("Promotional code incorrect")
  }
}
</script>

<body>
<form id="form3" name="form3" method="post" action="">
      <label for="promocode">Promotional Code:</label>
      <input type="text" name="promocode" id="promocode" />
    </form>
    <p></p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit Code" onclick="check()" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change to `window.location = "http://www.w3schools.com";`

Comment: On a sidenote, it's not usually smart to have things such as promotional codes laying around in the source files for HTML and/or Javascript. That way it would be easy to just check these files and type them in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`form`](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/guides/html_forms_basics) that your submit button is in, is being posted before the page has a chance to redirect.

Given that you're not posting any data, you don't really need either of the forms. If you want to surround the elements with something in order to add style, use a `div` instead.

Note that `window.location.assign` has been changed to `window.location` also.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function check(){
  var codeEntered = document.getElementById("promocode").value;
  if (codeEntered==40)
  {
    window.location = "http://www.w3schools.com";
  }
  else if(codeEntered == "")
  {
    alert("Please Enter a Promotional Code.")  
  }
  else
  {
    alert("Promotional code incorrect")
  }
}
</script>

<body>
      <label for="promocode">Promotional Code:</label>
      <input type="text" name="promocode" id="promocode" />

  <p>&nbsp;</p>

  <button type="button" value="Submit Code" onclick="check()" >Submit Code</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OMG THANKYOU!!!! definitely worked well, thank you so much!!!!!

Comment: glad I could help :) here's some more information on html forms you might find of use - http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/guides/html_forms_basics

Comment: JUst to be annoying if i wanted to change the website to another html document what will i need to change the link to

Comment: instead of `http://www.w3schools.com` ? you would put `myhtmlpage.html`, if it's in the same folder as your current page.

Comment: ok thanks, is this the same problem that occurs with my document.write function that is just showing up for 1 second and then getting redirected to the page taht you submittd the form on

Comment: potentially - you can `return false` or `preventDefault` on an event to prevent a form being submitted too. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to set the window.location property to a html anchor element instead of setting it to the location you want to send the page to.

try this instead:

```
window.location = "http://www.w3schools.com";
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work either, the code excecutes well but in using chrome the loading symbol occurs but the linked page doesnt show up at all it just seems to refresh the page

Comment: it works fine in the chrome web console, have you added the above exactly ? in place of the previous code you had

Comment: yea im sure i did, just a copy and paste? yes tried on second attempt but still no luck on it working

Comment: i am using dreamweaver cs6 aswell for website

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
window.location.assign("http://www.w3schools.com")
```

or

**EDIT:**

```
window.open('http://www.w3schools.com','_self',false)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work, I noticed on other pages that i have worked on i have outputted to a document.write file and you see a glimpse of it but refreshes and goes back to the page before the document.write. Could this be a problem with the code?

Comment: My first code was tested, so there was no reason to downvote it. Any ways check the edited code, work fine on my machine.

Comment: ok will definitely try that, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Still doesnt work on my computer even with the edit code

Answer (score 0):

try this:

location.href="http://www.w3schools.com";

It is probably faster, assigning property than calling a function.

Visit http://jsperf.com/location-href-vs-location-assign for more details.

You also need to include "return false;" in your JS function:

and make a call like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit Code" onclick="**return** check();" />
```

and javascript function like this:

```
function check() {
        window.location.href = "http://www.w3schools.com" ;
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: sorry to say, i have tried this aswell but doesnt work just refreshes the page, did you get it to work in the code i supplied above

Comment: have your added "return false;" in your javascript check() function?

Comment: yea tried that aswell still no luck

Comment: ok something very strange is happening on your setup, viewing the other comments you seem to be having trouble running any code to do this. I have used this code myself and it works, if you open chrome, right click, inspect element and move to console, you can run that line on its own and it will work. Is there something strange about your setup ? are you getting console errors ? how are you testing this ?

Comment: I have tried your code and its working fine with me.